# How to convert value of sin into the angle?

Tags: c++, trigonometry

For example I have a value 0.70, and it is a sin() for 45 degrees. I need a function, that will calculate me an angle from a sin. What function from C++ can help me?

Comment: Significant digits matter. `0.7 radians ~ 40 degrees`, while `0.70712 radians ~ 45.001 degrees`

Comment: [A good C++ reference site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) could be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::asin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/asin). This returns a value between `[-PI/2,+PI/2]`, to get degrees you multiply by `180` and divide by `PI`.

`result = std::asin(value) * 180 / PI`

`PI = 3.1415926535`